# Log4j terminal logs are executing but No Output file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

While executing the application, it is show the logs in the Eclipse IDE's console.
But it's not writing any data on to the external Log file

created simple application with adding log4j logs.

**Code**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloExample{
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HelloExample obj = new HelloExample();
        obj.runMe("Milinda");

    }

    private void runMe(String parameter){

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("This is debug : " + parameter);
        }

        if(logger.isInfoEnabled()){
            logger.info("This is info : " + parameter);
        }

        logger.warn("This is warn : " + parameter);
        logger.error("This is error : " + parameter);
        logger.fatal("This is fatal : " + parameter);

    }

}
```

**My Log4J Porperty File is as bellow**

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Projects\\HelloLogging\\test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your file appender to the RootLogger.   Try this...

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout, file <-- added file here

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Projects\\HelloLogging\\test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```